# Как добавить новый элемент в массив?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```
Products = [{ id: 1, name : 'product 1', price : 100, 
category: 'category_1' },
{ id: 2, name : 'product 2' , price : 700, category: 
'category_2' },
{ id: 3, name : 'product 3', price : 300, category: 
'category_3' }];
```

В него я хочу вставить дополнительный элемент :
`this.Products.push(4, 'product 4', 400, 'category_1')`. Получаю в результате ошибку в методе `push()` на `id`
вставляемого элемента - `Argument of type '11' is not  assignable to parameter of type.`

Что не так делается, в чём ошибка?

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of Products">
  <div *ngIf="item.id <= rows && item.category == this.category">
    <div *ngIf="item.price <= 500" class="table table-striped">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.price}}</td>
      <td>{{item.category}}</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary" id="but_Delete" (click)="delete(item.id)"> Удалить </button></td>
    </div>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Передаваемое значение должно быть объектом, а не отдельными значениями.

```
this.Products.push({id: 4, name:'product 4', price:400, category:'category_1' })
```

Comment: Пробовал добавить объектом таким способом:          var newElem = { id: 4, name : 'product 4' , price : 700, category: 'category_2' }
      this.Products.push(newElem) - ошибок нет, но и элемент не добавился.

Comment: Так как у Вас тоже пробовал - то же самое, объект не добавился почему-то.

Comment: объект то добавился, но вы наверное обновление не видите его. Как вы проверяете, что он добавился?

Comment: Да, действительно добавился элемент, но почему-то не выводится - буду разбираться, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: у вас наверное `products` не реактивный, поэтому при обновлении вы не видите изменений.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что такое реактивный products и как его сделать таковым?

Comment: Покажите лучше код компонента, где вы эти продукты выводите и места, где используете.

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let item of Products">
    <div *ngIf="item.id <= rows && item.category == this.category">
        <div *ngIf="item.price <= 500" class="table table-striped">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.price}}</td>
            <td>{{item.category}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" id="but_Delete" (click)="delete(item.id)"> Удалить </button></td>
        </div> ...

Comment: @Anton, странно, должно бы было добавлять.